# Could not load file or assembly (Visual Studio 2017 .NET Core)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have a set of dlls created in VS 2017 .NET Core that contain shared code that is used between several applications at my organization. The dlls were compiled and then added to a .NET Core app in VS2017. The project compiles perfectly and all references are found, but when I run the application I get an error that the DLL was not found. I've traced the path of the reference back to the actual DLL file, so I know it's there.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'OSPI.Framework.Core.Mvc, Version=6.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

I've done this exact thing dozens upon dozens of times in other applications written in .NET 4.6.2 and lower (VS 2015 and lower) with no issues. The way I set up the import this time is exactly the same as the previous times. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do both the project and dll target compatible frameworks?

Comment: Yeah, they're both configured as .NET Core 1.1 right now.

Comment: I encounter once the same trouble. I resolved on deleted the generated dll, rebuild the project, then readd the reference to the target project

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research it turns out this is a known bug in .NET Core. They say that it will be fixed in version 2.1.

Comment: How did you come with that any resource ?